# Widget in some android phone can not receive broadcast in AppWidgetProvider when app has been killed

Tags: android, android-widget

In the commom way, we receive events invoked by widget in AppWidgetProvider which is a BroadcastReceiver.But some Android Device can't not receive broadcast in AppWidgetProvider when the app is kill.

Any kind people can offer me some help?

Answer (score 0):

Now I know how to fix it.

In AppWidgetProvider, I use `PendingIntent.getService` instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` to bind event to RemoteView. And I handle the event from widget in a service.